# Generate independent random values from a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: r, distributions, python, random-generation, covariance-matrix

I am trying to independently select two sets of numbers (`set 1` and `set 2`) from a  bivariate normal distribution. I want the variance between the two to be equal and the correlation to be 0.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have access to a statistical software package like R or SAS?

Comment: @dsaxton I use R and Python. I am trying to implement this in python, but R would be OK too. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't NumPy have a way of generating normal variates?  If you want zero correlation then you can just simulate them separately from their marginal distributions.

Comment: @dsaxton Better yet, it has this (link below). My problem is, however, what to set cov as. That is, my problem here is more conceptual that anything. The distribution is meant to be circular (i.e., correlation 0). http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html#numpy.random.multivariate_normal

Comment: To make the distribution circular, it seems to me that I'd make them the same, e,g., cov = `[ [1,0.5], [1,0.5] ]` ... Which 'makes sense' I'm just not sure if it's correct.

Comment: @InNoam You said you wanted zero correlation, but now you're saying you want a covariance matrix with non-zero off diagonals?  Which one?  To make this even simpler, generate independent observations from the *same* normal distribution and divide it into two groups.  That's all you need to do.

Comment: @dsaxton zero correlation.  Moreover, perhaps this is just stemming from my confusion, but how would sampling from a normal distribution provide me with samples from a bivariate normal distribution?

Comment: @InNoam Because zero correlation implies independence for random variables that are distributed multivariate normal.

Comment: @dsaxton thank you as well. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a spherical distribution, you just need to specify the covariance matrix appropriately.  The covariance matrix will be square and symmetrical, with the number of rows / columns equal to the number of variates you are generating (in your case 2x2).  Going down the main diagonal, you need to enter the same value each time.  It can be any value, so long as they are all the same.  All the off-diagonal elements must be $0$.  That's it.

For example (using `R`):

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(4776)
mvrnorm(2, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=rbind(c(1, 0),
                                  c(0, 1) ))
#          [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] -1.57177  0.4407796
# [2,] -1.02704 -0.1355521
```

(Note: `Sigma` is the variance-covariance matrix.)

Comment: or `np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0],[ [1,0] ,[0,1] ], 2)` in python's numpy. Very obvious in hindsight.... Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: This works of course, but isn't `matrix(rnorm(2 * n), nrow = n, ncol = 2)` easier?  In Python `np.random.randn(n, 2)` would be enough.

Comment: @dsaxton, yes that would work. However, as *an answer to this question*, I think it wouldn't provide the conceptual clarity the OP was after.